# not opening dataconnection using oledb

Tags: c#, sql, insert, oledb

I have this code which works properly in fidderent form. but somehow, in the specific form it doesn't work and I get this error(in the line `connction.Open();`) `Unspecified error`

the code suppose to add multiple rows into a table.
here is the code:

```
                    for (int i = 0; st1.Length > i; i++)
                    UpdateDataBase(st1[i]);


private void UpdateDataBase(char letter)
    {
        int serialPro = 0;
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                  "Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo ";
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    //get the last!
                    while (reader.Read())
                        serialPro = reader.GetInt32(0);

                }
                sql = "INSERT INTO tblOrderAA (orderAASerialPro, orderAACodon1) "
                   + " values (?, ?)";
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAASerialPro", serialPro);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAACodon1", letter);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error in:" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I know I can use MAX to get the last one. But it works rightly in different Form. So I insist to understand why!
thank u all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistake you did not close reader so try to add it

```
while (reader.Read())
    serialPro = reader.GetInt32(0);
reader.Close();
```

**EDIT**

Make what i say (for remove future bags)

Make `connection` as static somewhere (for example in program.cs, will be better if you will make static classs) and then call it in this way

```
        if(Program.connection.State==System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            Program.connection.Open();
```

Comment: but it stops debugging before this line. see the question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently. Try runnig the code with connection opening and closing with elevated privelages

Comment: I was facing the same issue in a asp .net sharepoint project.  Tried all different connection strings possible. But finally tried opening the connection within    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges this gives the code full access rights even if the user dosent have complete rights. Some how this resolved the issue. the eqvivalent fro this in asp .net acc to me is the above code.

Comment: If it is still not resolve try using other open source Excel libraries they are easier to use and provide lot more functionalities. This is a good library. NPOI For Excel 2003 Open Source http://www.leniel.net/2009/07/creating-excel-spreadsheets-xls-xlsx-c.html

Comment: nevermind. I found a solution. I opened the connection just once, and its working properly..